# Имя временного файла

Tags: php

Мне нужно узнать имя время файла, создающегося функцией tmpfile(). Вот пример кода:

```
<?php
$temp = tmpfile();
fwrite($temp, "записываем во временный файл");
fseek($temp, 0);
echo fread($temp, 1024);
fclose($temp); // происходит удаление файла
?>
```

Можно ли достать имя файла? Директорию куда он будет записан я знаю.

Comment: `stream_get_meta_data($temp )`  http://php.net/manual/ru/function.stream-get-meta-data.php

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$tmpfname = tempnam("/tmp", "FOO");

$handle = fopen($tmpfname, "w");
fwrite($handle, "записываем в во временный файл");
fclose($handle);

// здесь мы чего-нибудь делаем

unlink($tmpfname);
?>
```

пример с документацию я думаю лучше для этих целей использовать tempnam() функцию

Comment: Я знаю. У меня fopen отключена, никуда писать не могу. Поэтому приходиться крутиться так.

Comment: @FilippMustang Если она отключена значит все файловые операции запрещены либо доступа нет. Что за хостинг сервер локал?

Comment: Да нет, уже разобрался с помощью stream_get_meta_data(), там нашел путь. Временный файл создается. У меня не хостинг, я не совсем веб-разработчик, на это дело свои интересы. Но все равно спасибо за ответ.